# Validando um modelo com cross validation (regressão logística). Para que serve o Grid search?

Tags: machine-learning

```
scores = cross_val_score(logmodel,y_test.astype(float).reshape(-1, 1),predictions.reshape(-1, 1),
                        scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",cv=10)


log_rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-scores)

def display_scores(scores):
    print("Scores: ", scores)
    print("Mean: ",scores.mean())
    print("Standard Deviation: ", scores.std())


display_scores(log_rmse_scores)
```

Saída:

```
Scores:  [0.02972702 0.02972702 0.02972702 0.02972702 0.02972702 0.02972702
 0.02972775 0.02972775 0.02972775 0.02972775]
Mean:  0.029727313479823336
Standard Deviation:  3.574977450912211e-07
```

Pelo que eu entendi, este ainda não é o melhor modelo: eu preciso "tunar" o modelo buscando os melhores hiperparâmetros com Grid Search, é isso mesmo?

Que hiperparâmetros sao esses na regressão logística?
Ao final do processo, o que será o modelo?

Estou sem entender o que obter no final.

Answer (score 1):

Na regressão logística não há hiperparâmetros para *tunar* a não ser que seja uma regressão logística com regularização.

Outra coisa que pode ser *tunada* na regressão logística são as variáveis (colunas da tabela X) que entram no modelo. Pelo que entendi do seu código, a tabela X possui apenas 1 coluna, então não teria o que *tunar* neste caso.

Comment: tenho 47 colunas/features. O que seria a regularização?

Comment: Regularização é quando você coloca na sua função de perda uma penalização na magnitude dos pesos estimados. Em geral a força dessa penalização é escolhida via validação cruzada. Você pode fazer o que é chamado de RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination) via validação cruzada também para encontrar um modelo que use menos variáveis.